# how can i make socket connection run in the background process for android and ios in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have tried to run socket connection in the background process for android and ios, to display notifications using notifee package, what I'm trying to do is when the app is killed the service is going to still run in background process and display notification when the app is killed.

Comment: Please look into https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions and https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android

Comment: i used react native background actions but couldn't figure out how to make it work

Comment: Did you the example they posted https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions/blob/master/examples/backgroundExample/App.tsx

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.